Calculating the limit of a quotient of integral functions
I am deeply struggling to compute the following limit:
$$\lim_{t \ \rightarrow \ + \infty} \frac{\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2 \ \mathrm{e}^{-t\,x^2} \sin 2x \ \mathrm{d}x}{\left( \int_0^{\pi/2} \mathrm{e}^{-t\,x^2} \sin 2x \ \mathrm{d}x \right)^2}$$
I have checked the result using Mathematica, that gave a value of $1$. But I have no idea about how to prove it. I am trying a lot but could not find any hint. I suppose that trying to compute the antiderivatives or the undefinite integrals themselves is useless and way too complicate, and thinks that there should be a simpler method, but I could not find it.

This is not the complete answer but it may help. (I'll try to edit the answer later)
Edit: FINALLY. Got it.
If you assume a function
$$
I(t)=\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}e^{-tx^{2}}sin(2x)dx}
$$
Then it's derivative with respect to t will be the function inside the limit. (Using feynman's differentiation under integral)
$$
I'(t)=\frac{\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}x^{2}e^{-tx^{2}}sin(2x)dx}{(\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}e^{-tx^{2}}sin(2x)dx)^{2}}
$$
So, we want
$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty} I'(t)
$$
Now, by reversing L'Hopital, this is the same as (we can do this because both numerator and denominator tend to infinity as t -> infinity)
$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty} I'(t)= \lim_{t\to+\infty} \frac{I(t)}{t}
\\= \lim_{t\to+\infty} \frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}te^{-tx^{2}}sin(2x)dx}
$$
Edit:
Now of course we can shift the limit to just the denominator.
$$
\frac{1}{\lim_{t\to+\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}te^{-tx^{2}}sin(2x)dx}
$$
Now, there are two methods - one by approximation and the other by rigorous maths:
Approximation: The function inside the integral is zero at any x>>0, so only the values which are really close to zero matter. Therefore, since we need only the small values we can say:
$$
sin(2x)≈2x
\\
\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}te^{-tx^{2}}sin(2x)dx ≈ \int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}te^{-tx^{2}}(2x)dx
$$
And so, now it's pretty easy
$$
u=tx^{2}
\\=> \int_{0}^{\frac{π^{2}t}{4}}e^{-u}du
=  1-e^{-π^{2}t/4}
=  1\ \ [as\  t\to\infty,\ e^{-π^{2}t/4}\to0]
\\=> \lim_{t\to\infty}(...) = 1
$$
Actual math: (Taylor series)
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}te^{-tx^{2}}sin(2x)dx
\\= \int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}te^{-tx^{2}}(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}(2x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!})dx
\\= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)!}\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}e^{-tx^{2}}(4x²)^{k}(2xtdx)
\\
\\u=tx^{2}
\\=>\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)!}\int_{0}^{\frac{π}{2}}e^{-u}(4u/t)^{k}du
$$
Now, for any value of k other than 0, the integral always -> 0 when t->infinity  due to 1/t term (you can try for yourself)
But for k=0, the only term we get is:
$$
\\=> \int_{0}^{\frac{π^{2}t}{4}}e^{-u}du
=  1-e^{-π^{2}t/4}
=  1\ \ [again]
\\=> \lim_{t\to\infty}(...) = 1
$$
So the answer is 1.

Thanks a lot, that's excellent (and very elegant, to my opinion) !
